# ASUS EAH5770 CuCore problem: VLC Stutting!

Tags: vlc-media-player, amd-radeon

Hello to everyone and thank you in advance to all the people that will want help me. Like in the title my problem concernig this boring stutting when i play a Tv series episodes or a film on VLC whit my mew PC.

PC components are:

- AMD Phenom II X4 955 Black Box 125W
- Asus M4A785TD-M EVO Radeon HD5770 1GB GDDR5
- Asus CoolerMaster GX 650W
- G.Skill 2x2GB PC3-12800 1600Mhz-787 4GBECO
- Western Digital 1TB SATAII 64MB
- Monitor: SyncMaster 920Nw
- OS: Windows XP 32 bit

Display adapter drivers are updates at the latest release (catalyst 10.4) and also the ATi Vga bios are updated Besides when i play the same episode with DivX Plus Player i have video and audio stutting. I can play very well Dragon Age Origin and other games but i'm unable to see a beautiful movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I believe there is no enough power somewhere. But there is a way (many ways). You have to wait for VLC 1.1.0 release, since video acceleration will come to that version.

For exampe, the use of DXVA (DirectX Video Acceleration). Until then, you can use [CCCP project](http://cccp-project.net/) (mpc-hc+essential applications). Install it. Launch `Media Player Classic Home Cinema`. Go to View -> Options. Now, go to Internal filters. At the right side (**transform filters**) select `H264/AVC (DXVA)` and `VC1 (DXVA)`. Click OK, close mpc-hc, and start your movie with it. If you've done everything OK, you will see a `Playing[DXVA]` at the bottom. (Don't worry if you won't see the message. It can happen that you need a ffdshow update, just comment and I'll write it down how you can do that.) Here is a picture how it should look like:

[image]

Besides this method, you can use [CoreAVC](http://corecodec.com/products/coreavc). It's a proprietary, non-free codec. For ATI it won't support GPU decoding, but it can use all the CPU cores. That should already do the job. (Later there will be some ATI support as far as I know, but there is none yet.)

---

Oh I forgot an important thing. UPDATE your [DirectX](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/resultsForProduct.aspx?displaylang=en&productID=9C954C37-1ED1-4846-8A7D-85FC422D1388).

Comment: Thank You so much Shiki! 
I've solved the problem using MPC-HC like you tell me.
Now i will wait the 1.1.0 Vlc release.
I've posten on so many italian and english forum and here with just one answer i solved my problem. I repeat Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use VLC 1.1.0 or 1.2.0 packages. These don't need an install, just unpack it and use them. (They are development packages, expect that they won't work correctly sometimes, and its not a given that they will start at all.) >> http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/win32/last/ , http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/testing/